# XMLHttpRequest read progressive data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to download an image via Ajax (XHR2) while displaying a progress bar and also progressively displaying the image.

The progress event gives me the data I need for the progress bar (it works well), but I can only display the image in the load event because the load events response property contains the blob, while in the progress event the response property is null.

Is it possible to show the image progressively while it is downloading?

Are the responseText, responseXML and response set only in the load event?